Why is volume changing even with a Poisson's ratio of 0.5?
We know that Poisson's ratio, $$\sigma=\frac{-∆r}{∆l}×\frac{l}{r}$$
Let us take a cylindrical wire of radius 1m and length of 1 metre. Let the Poisson's ratio be 0.5 and the increase in length be 0.2 m . So we can say,
$-0.5×0.2 = ∆r \implies ∆r=-0.1$
But than the new volume becomes $V_f=π(0.9)^2(1.2)\neq V_i $ because $V_i=π$. I am pretty sure I am mistaken somewhere . I just can't figure out where. Any help will be appreciated.

Because you are not anywhere near the small deformation limit. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_ratio

First, $0.5 \times 0.2 = 0.1$. So you really have $(0.9)^2 \times 1.2 = 0.972$.
Second, the linear relationship is only approximate, valid for very small values of $\Delta L$, and 0.2 is not very small compared to 1.
The true formula as derived on Wikipedia would be
$$\left(1 + \frac{\Delta L}{L}\right)^{-\nu} = 1 + \frac{\Delta R}{R}$$
So for a 0.2 m stretch, you get $\Delta r = - 0.087\dots $

Ok. Fixed the mistake.

For an incompressible rod, $$\epsilon_r=\epsilon_{\theta}=\frac{\Delta r}{r}=-0.5\epsilon_z=-0.5\frac{\Delta l}{l}$$So the volumetric strain is $$\epsilon_V=\epsilon_r+\epsilon_{\theta}+\epsilon_z=0$$
